# Calling a C library module with ctypes gives false results

Tags: c, python-2.7, ctypes

I created a simple C library file to test how I can access C functions with ctypes.

The function in the C file named tetr.c reads:

```
double square(double x){
    return x*x;
}
```

So it returns the square of the number.

I've compiled it to an object file using the following:

```
gcc -c tetr.c -o tetr.o
```

and to a shared object file using:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,library.so -o tetr.so tetr.o
```

So far so good. I call the ipython shell, and set as the variable lib my library:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("tetr.so")
```

Naturally, when I'd call `lib.square(ctypes.c_double(2.0))` it should give me `4.0`. Instead I get `1`. And same happens with any number I insert in the function square, even zero.

A short notice, I used `ctypes.c_double` inside my function because without that I get zero when I input an integer and

```
ArgumentError: argument 1: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 1
```

when I input a float/double.

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to convert (cast) the return value too?

Comment: I don't see why I should. Will try it though, thanks for the thought.

Comment: You need to tell `ctypes` that the function returns a `double`. It can't figure that out itself, so unless you tell it otherwise it assumes every function's return type is `int`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types

Comment: Thanks, that along with setting the argument type as `double` worked.

Comment: If you could rewrite this comment as an answer to the post, I'd check it as the solution.

Comment: You need to set the `restype` of the function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `ctypes` that the function returns a double. It can't figure that out itself, so unless you tell it otherwise it assumes every function's return type is `int`. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#return-types

For example:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("tetr.so")
lib.square.restype = ctypes.c_double
ret = lib.square(ctypes.c_double(2.0))
```